# Do $x_0, k$ and $q$ exist as a solution?

Tags: functions, recursive-algorithms

> Given the recursive function:
>   $$x_{n+1}=\sqrt[k]{x_n^k + q}$$ where $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and **$q, k \in \mathbb{Z}$**. Such that: $$x_{Fn(1)}=x_{Fn(2)}=x_1$$ $$x_{Fn(n)}-x_{Fn(n-1)}=q$$ where $Fn(n)$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonnaci number.

Is there any possible solution for $x_0, k$ & $q$?

Answer (score 0):

There would be infinite solutions, with conditions based on the values of $k$ and $x_0$.

The value $q$ can be easily found by solving the second and third equations using $n=2$.

Using $n=1$, and knowing the Fibonacci numbers are $F_n(0)=0$ and $F_n(1)=1$, we can eliminate $x_1$ as part of $x_0$, which leaves $x_0$ and $k$ with just one (first) equation reformulated.

We then find that there are zero to infinite solutions for $x_0$ depending on the value of $k$, and zero to infinite solutions for $k$ depending on the value of $x_0$, with finite solutions in-between.

Comment: Just to clarify, do we agree that $x_{13} - x_{21} = q$?

Comment: If $k=2$, how should I find the general formula for $x_0$ and $q$ such that $\{ x_1, x_2, x_3, x_5, x_8, x_{13},... x_{Fn(n)}\}$ is an arithmetic series with $q$ as the difference?

Comment: The last equation proves what you state: $x_{13}-x_{21}=q$ for $n=8$. On the next comment, if what you are asking is the first phrase (the second phrase is already shown by the last two equations): if $k=2$, find general formula for $x_0$ and $q$, then plug in $k=2$ and $x_0$ in the first equation ($x_1$ is eliminated as part of $x_0$ by third equation) and you will find an algebraic equation of $x_0$. You can then find a general formula of $x_0$ using algebra.